# Scraping pricing off a search bar from a website with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of part numbers to be looked up from the search bar on: https://www.partsfinder.com/catalog/preview?q=0119000230this site.

I want to collect the prices off the results.

Here's what I put up together but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.partsfinder.com/catalog/preview?q=0119000230')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
resultsRow = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'search_result_row'})
results = []
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: there's no `search_result_row` class on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically loaded via xhr POST request. You can see this in the dev tools of browser when refreshing the page. You can minimize the request to the following:

```
import requests

data = {"partOptionFilter":{"PartNumber":"0119000230","AlternativeOemId":"17155"}}
r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions',json=data).json()
print(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However I'm getting the error below:

Comment: Please include error as code still runs fine for me,

Comment: Omitting some lines b/c o/w exceed limit:Traceback (most recent call last):
  .....
  File "C:\Users\\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.partsfinder.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Catalog/Preview (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031B6B10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Seems like it is refusing your connection. Not sure if somehow it is blocking your IP. Have you tried under a different ip?

Comment: Yeah it was due to the company firewall..fixed that now.

Comment: Your code worked!  here's my code using loop, now getting the error "DataFrame" object is not callable..import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\Copy of MIC Parts Review - July 26 19.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Product code'])

#print(PN)
i = 0

while i < len (PN):

    data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN(i), "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
    r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data).json()
    print(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])
    i=i+1

Comment: Yep just accepted.  I also added what I have so far to original post, getting the "Dataframe object is not callable" error, would appreciate it if you could let me know what's wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't edit the original question as it invalidates answers. You should open a new question with the current code and explain what isn't working. You can rollback your [edit] to the previous version.

Comment: I suspect you can't do PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Product code'])  as df is already a dataframe? Maybe replace with df.columns = ['columnName']

Comment: I figured it out thanks! - yeah it's due to the df, need to use iloc[] instead of len().  However what is the AlternativeoemId in your code?  I only have the Partnumbers in my list, not sure how I can include the AlternativeOemId in my loop.

Comment: or I guess my question is, do I have to use "AlternativeOemId"? tried to delete it from the code but gets an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197180/discussion-between-vic-and-qharr).